# Region of Baden-Württemberg is not shown in geo-chart

Tags: looker-studio

I use the geo-diagram to display the origin of my users filtered by region (the federal states in Germany). If I select the "Region" geographic dimension, it shows me data for all federal states except for Baden-Württemberg. However, the "City" dimension shows many users from the cities in the region. Anyone have any tips on how to fix this bug?

However, the "City" dimension shows many users from the cities in the region. So the data is there, but just not shown in the geo-chart. Anyone have any tips on how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

Both Google Analytics and Google Ads output the region as "Baden-Wurttemberg" whereas Google Maps require "Baden-Württemberg".

This custom dimension should fix it:

```
IF(Region = "Baden-Wurttemberg","Baden-Württemberg", Region)
```