Region Baden-Württemberg in Germany is not showing in Looker Studio map chart
We want to get 'Region' data in Google Looker Studio from the German region: Baden-Württemberg.
All of Germany is showing data except Baden-Württemberg. We are using the geo-diagram to display the origin of all users.
I saw that both Google Analytics and Google Ads output the region as "Baden-Wurttemberg" whereas Google Maps require "Baden-Württemberg".
Does anyone know a solution to show data?
I tried to switch to 'City'. I see that there is data from the region.

Is it partially/fully solving your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77858569/region-of-baden-w%c3%bcrttemberg-is-not-shown-in-geo-chart?rq=2
